# Acceso de seguridad para poder visualizar reportes hechos en pdf desde C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cordial saludo equipo espero que esten bien, agradezco si por favor me pueden decir que debo de hacer para arreglar el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta al momento de querer generar un reporte de una aplicacion en C# Asp.Net con base de datos SQL server en donde dicho reporte se visualiza en PDF, el codigo que tengo para crear el informe o reporte es el siguiente:

private void crearPDF()
{
PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(@"C:\Windows\Reporte.pdf ");  //1 Oct puede ser remplazado por la carpeta o ruta de carpetas en donde querramos almacenar el reporte   C:\Usuarios\Reporte.pdf
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
//usa tipos tipograficos 1 pulgada = 72 pt (puntos tipograficos) tamaño carta en 8 pulgadas y media X 11 pulgadas (8 1/2 X 11) (612 X 792) el calculo lo hacen en el minuto 8 del video
PageSize tamanioH = new PageSize(792, 612);

```
        Document documento = new Document(pdf, tamanioH); //1 Oct PageSize.LETTER son hojas tamaño carta

        documento.SetMargins(60, 20, 55, 20);    //SetMargins  son las margenes
        PdfFont fontColumnas = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA_BOLD);
        PdfFont fontContenido = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
        string[] columnas = { "idmov", "Nombre_almacen", "Fecha_compra", "Rifa_de" };
        float[] tamanios = { 2, 6, 6, 6 };
        iText.Layout.Element.Table tabla = new iText.Layout.Element.Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(tamanios)); // 1 Oct ojo en el video tan solo aparece Table tabla =Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(tamanios));
        tabla.SetWidth(UnitValue.CreatePercentValue(100));

        foreach (string columna in columnas)
        {
            tabla.AddHeaderCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(columna).SetFont(fontColumnas)));

        }

        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("select * from compyrifas where Nombre_almacen like '" + TextBox1.Text + "%'", cn1);  //
        cn1.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
            {  //para que nos muestre el contenido con mas datos
                tabla.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(reader["idmov"].ToString()).SetFont(fontContenido)));
                tabla.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(reader["Nombre_almacen"].ToString()).SetFont(fontContenido)));
                tabla.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(reader["Fecha_compra"].ToString()).SetFont(fontContenido)));
                tabla.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph(reader["Rifa_de"].ToString()).SetFont(fontContenido)));
            }
        }

        documento.Add(tabla);
        documento.Close();

        var logo = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(ImageDataFactory.Create("C:/Users/Marko/Desktop/PDF/logo.png")).SetWidth(50); //ojo cambiar la ruta
        var plogo = new Paragraph("").Add(logo);

        var titulo = new Paragraph("Reporte de compras y rifas");
        titulo.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        titulo.SetFontSize(12);


        var dfecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        var dhora = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
        var fecha = new Paragraph("Fecha:" + dfecha + "\nHora: " + dhora);
        fecha.SetFontSize(12);

        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("Reporte.pdf"), new PdfWriter("Reportecomprasyrifas.pdf"));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

        int numeros = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();

        for (int i = 1; i <= numeros; i++)
        {
            PdfPage pagina = pdfDoc.GetPage(i);
            float y = (pdfDoc.GetPage(i).GetPageSize().GetTop() - 15);
            doc.ShowTextAligned(plogo, 40, y, i, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
            doc.ShowTextAligned(titulo, 150, y - 15, i, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
            doc.ShowTextAligned(fecha, 520, y - 15, i, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);

            doc.ShowTextAligned(new Paragraph(String.Format("Pagina {0} de {1}", i, numeros)), pdfDoc.GetPage
                (i).GetPageSize().GetWidth() / 2, pdfDoc.GetPage(i).GetPageSize().GetBottom() + 30, i,
                TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);  //Ancho de la hoja
        }
        doc.Close();
    }
```

Al correr el programa y querer abrir el reporte o informe me muestra un error, que es el siguiente:

Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.

---

Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso 'C:\Windows\Reporte.pdf'.
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso 'C:\Windows\Reporte.pdf'.

ASP.NET no está autorizado para obtener acceso al recurso solicitado. Considere la posibilidad de conceder derechos de acceso al recurso para la identidad de solicitud de ASP.NET. ASP.NET tiene una identidad de proceso base (normalmente {MACHINE}\ASPNET en IIS 5 o Network Service en IIS 6 e IIS 7, y la identidad del grupo de aplicaciones configurada en IIS 7.5) que se utiliza si la aplicación no se va a suplantar. Si la aplicación se va a suplantar mediante , la identidad será el usuario anónimo (generalmente IUSR_MACHINENAME) o el usuario solicitado autenticado.

Para conceder a ASP.NET acceso a un archivo, desde el explorador de archivos, haga clic con el botón secundario del mouse en el archivo, elija "Propiedades" y seleccione la pestaña Seguridad. Haga clic en "Agregar" para agregar el usuario o grupo adecuado. Resalte la cuenta de ASP.NET y active las casillas según el acceso deseado.

Según esa solicitud lo que yo hago es ir a la carpeta C:\Windows (Que es en donde tengo almacenado el Reporte.pdf), dar click derecho luego voy a la pestaña Seguridad e intentarle dar permisos a todos los usuarios que tengo en mi equipo, pero no me permite asignar opciones de seguridad adicionales a cada usuario, pues se deshabilita el botón "Agregar" , para permitir asignar permisos a los usuarios.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar para arreglar este inconveniente!

---

Muchas gracias Roberto y Eduardo, por sus respuestas pero mi pregunta que me surge con la soluciones que ustedes me brindan es que ¿Es necesario siempre configurar las carpetas (asignando permisos usuario)?, es que la idea es que el usuario pueda almacenar la carpeta en donde desee.

Comment: Y por que el reporte en c:/windows, esa es la carpeta de el sistema no deberías trabajar con ella, genera tu reporte en otra carpeta, en esa otra carpeta puedes asignarle a un usuario permisos para lectura y escritura para el usuario iis, o le puedes generar otro usuario y asignarlo en el iis a tu aplicación.

Comment: Saludos. Prueba con una temporal que tengas (por ejemplo `%temp%` -esta es como una variable de entorno; puede apuntar a `c:\windows\temp`-) o en su defecto (mas deseable) una ruta (igual temporal) a tu sitio. Igual ya en productivo